# How to show direct message to web page on dart language

Tags: dart

how to show a message look like on php

echo "helloworld"; 

But in dart
I try

```
#import ('dart:html');
void main () {
  var textElement = new Element.html("Hello world");
  window.document.body.nodes.add(textElement );
}
```

but it not work, i don't like `document.query('#idname').innerHTML` 

any way to do what i want,
thank everybody.

Comment: Just fyi, query is top-level, so you can just use "query.('...')".  I would also add that in your example 'document.body.innerHTML = 'Hello World' would work just as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an actual element to the page.

```
#import ('dart:html');
void main () {
  var textElement = new Element.html("<p>Hello world</p>");
  document.body.nodes.add(textElement );
}
```

that is you use `<p>Hello world</p>` instead of just `Hello world`.